# Firebase Hosting - how to make a webpage like /file.json

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My firebase hosted webpage has a url like my_custom_name.firebasewebapp.com. I would like to create a page 
that contains a json file at my_custom_name.firebasewebapp.com/file.json.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deploy the file just like any other static web content (html, css, js) you would place in the public folder.  All the files in that folder will get deployed.